Я рехеширую ключи, после увеличения вместимости базы данных, в этот момент у меня теряются данные, не могу понять почему
Функции подписаны, потерю зафиксировал при занесении элемента в список List(Для повторяющихся ключей) Проблема возникает в функции рехеширования, имена не отображаются, а я работаю с ними, как мне это исправить?
//headers.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map> // Для записи кол-ва повторений одинаковых ключей
#include <fstream>
enum Gender {male, female};



class Data {
private:

    std::string name = "";
    int age;
    Gender gender;
    double salary;
public:
    Data() {};
    Data(int age, Gender gender, double salary) : age(age), gender(gender), salary(salary) {}

    ~Data() {
        name = "";
        age = 0;
        gender = male;
        salary = 0;
    }

    friend class BD;
    friend class List;

    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Data& data);
    friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& in, Data& data);

    void GetInfo();
    Data& operator =(const Data& a);

};

class Node {
    Data data;
    Node* pNext;
    Node* pPrev;
public:
    Node() : pNext(nullptr), pPrev(nullptr) {}
    Node(Node* prev, const Data& info) : data(info) {
        pNext = prev->pNext; // сохраняем указатель на текущий
        prev->pNext = this; // привязываем текущий к предыдущему как следующий
        pPrev = prev; // привязываем предыдущий к текущему как предыдущий
        pNext->pPrev = this; // привязываем к следующему текущий как предыдущий

    }

    ~Node() {
        if (pPrev != nullptr) pPrev->pNext = pNext;
        if (pNext != nullptr) pNext->pPrev = pPrev;

        pNext = nullptr; pPrev = nullptr;
    }

    friend class List;

};

class List {
    Node Head;
    Node Tail;
    int size;
public:

    List() {
        Head.pNext = &Tail;
        Tail.pPrev = &Head;
        size = 0;
    }

    // Описание функций в List.cpp файле
    void AddToHead(const Data& data);
    void AddToTail(const Data& data);
    void GetAllInfo();
    void GetInfo(const std::string& name);
    
    void WriteFile();
    
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Data& data);
    friend class BD;
};

class BD {
private:
    Data* elements; 
    int* listskey; // Зачем-то нужно, уже не помню
    int countlists; // сторонняя переменная
    List l1;
    std::map<int, int> repeatkeys; // запись сколько раз повторяется каждый ключ
    bool repeat; // переменная для проверки на повтор ключа
    int capacity = 4; // вместимость базы
    int size = 0; // кол-во записей 
    int rehashingcount = 0; // кол-во рехеширований из-за увилечения вместимости
public:
    BD() : elements(new Data[4]) {}

    // Описание функций в HeshBD.cpp файле
    int hashing(const std::string& name);
    void rehashing(const int& rehashingcount);
    void realloc();
    void check();

    void GetAllInfo(const BD& a);
    void GetInfo(const std::string& name);
    
    void KeyListsArr(int key);


    void WriteFile();
    void ReadFile(List& list2);

    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Data& data);
    friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& in, Data& data);
    friend class Data;

    Data& operator [] (const std::string& name);
    

};

//HeshBD.cpp
#include "Headers.h"

//Функция хеширования ключа
int BD::hashing(const std::string& name) {

    int temp = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
        temp += static_cast<int>(name[i]);
    }

    return temp % capacity;
}
//Функция рехеширования после увеличения вместимости базы
void BD::rehashing(const int& rehashingcount) {

    int PrevCapacity = capacity / 2 ;
    Data* Temp = new Data[PrevCapacity];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < PrevCapacity; i++) {
        Temp[i] = elements[i];
    }

    delete[] elements;
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < PrevCapacity; i++) {
        if (!(Temp[i].name.empty())) {
            int temp = hashing(Temp[i].name);
            elements[temp] = Temp[i];
        }
    }
    
}
//Функция увеличения вместимости базы
void BD::realloc() {
    rehashingcount++;
    Data* New = new Data[(capacity) * 2];

        for (size_t i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
            New[i] = elements[i];
        }
        delete[] elements;

        elements = std::move(New);
        capacity *= 2;
        rehashing(rehashingcount);

}
//Функция проверки необходимости увеличивать базу
void BD::check() {
    double count = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {

        if (elements[i].name.empty()) count++;
    }

    if (static_cast<double>(count / capacity) < static_cast<double>(static_cast<double>(3) / 4)) this->realloc();
}
//Функция, записывающая повторяющиеся ключи
void BD::KeyListsArr(int key) {

    if (countlists > 1) {
        int* temp = new int[countlists - 1];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < countlists - 1; i++) {
            temp[i] = listskey[i];
        }
        delete[] listskey;
        listskey = new int[countlists];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < countlists - 1; i++) {
            listskey[i] = temp[i];
        }
        delete[] temp;
        listskey[countlists - 1] = key;
    }
    else {
        listskey = new int[countlists];
        listskey[countlists - 1] = key;
    }
}


//Функция вывода всей информации из базы в консоль
void BD::GetAllInfo(const BD& a) {

    if(!repeatkeys.empty()) l1.GetAllInfo();
    std::cout << "From BD:\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
        if (!elements[i].name.empty()) {
            std::cout << "Name: " << elements[i].name << std::endl;
            std::string gend = "female";
            if (elements[i].gender == 0) gend = "male";
            std::cout << "Data: " << elements[i].age << "\t" << gend << "\t" << elements[i].salary << "\n\n";
        }
    }//Отделить вывод для ключей, в которых содержится список
}
//Функция вывода информации по имени
void BD::GetInfo(const std::string& name) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int key = hashing(name);
    std::cout << "Searching by name:\n";
    if (!repeatkeys.count(key)) {
        if (elements[key].name == name) {
            std::cout << "Name: " << elements[key].name << std::endl;
            std::string gend = "female";
            if (elements[key].gender == 0) gend = "male";
            std::cout << "Data: " << elements[key].age << "\t" << gend << "\t" << elements[key].salary << "\n\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Name: " << name << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Data: " <<  "Not Found!\n\n";
        }
    }
    else { // Найти элемент в списке List
        l1.GetInfo(name);
        
    }
}
//Функция вывода информации элемента Data
void Data::GetInfo() {
    std::cout << "Name: " << name << std::endl;
    std::string gend = "female";
    if (gender == 0) gend = "male";
    std::cout << "Data: " << age << "\t" << gend << "\t" << salary << "\n\n";
}

//Функция записи базы вместе со списком в файл
void BD::WriteFile() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    std::ofstream file("BD.txt");
    if (!file) {
        std::cout << "Ошибка открытия файла\n";
    }
    else {
        if(!repeatkeys.empty()) l1.WriteFile();
            for (size_t i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
                int key = hashing(elements[i].name);

                file << elements[i];

            }
    }
    file.close();
}

// Для присваивания значения элементам Data
Data& Data::operator =(const Data& data) { 
    
        age = data.age;
        gender = data.gender;
        salary = data.salary;
    
    /*else pub();*/
    return *this;

}
// Для присвоения значения ключа
Data& BD::operator [] (const std::string& name) {
    check();
    int key = hashing(name);
    if (repeat == 1) {

        int temp = listskey[countlists - 1];
        l1.AddToTail(elements[temp]);
        //countlists++;
        repeatkeys[temp] += 1;
        repeat = 0;
    }
    if (elements[key].name.empty()) {
        

        this->elements[key].name = name;
        size++;
        return elements[key];
    }

    else { 
        if (elements[key].name == name) {
            

            elements[key].name = name;
            elements[key].age = 0;
            elements[key].gender = male;
            elements[key].salary = 0;
            return elements[key];

        }
        else {
            bool other1 = 0;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < countlists; i++) {
                if (listskey[i] == key) other1 = 1;
            }
            if(other1) {
                repeat = 1;
                
            }
            else {
                if (repeatkeys[key] < 2) repeat = 1;
                countlists++;
                KeyListsArr(key);
                l1.AddToTail(elements[key]);
            }
            
            repeatkeys[key] += 1;
            elements[key].name = name;
            elements[key].age = 0;
            elements[key].gender = male;
            elements[key].salary = 0;
            size++;
            return elements[key];

        }
        //Перехеширование массива ключей, которые повторяются
    }

    

}

//Для записи в файл
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Data& data) {
    
    
     
        if (!data.name.empty()) {
            out << "Name: " << data.name << "\t";
            std::string gend = "female";
            if (data.gender == 0) gend = "male";
            out << "Data: " << data.age << "\t" << gend << "\t" << data.salary << "\n";
        }

        return out;
}

//List.cpp
#include "Headers.h"
//Функция, добавляющая элемент в начало списка
void List::AddToHead(const Data& data) {
    new Node(&Head, data);
    size++;
}
//Функция, добавляющая элемент в конец списка
void List::AddToTail(const Data& data) {
    new Node(Tail.pPrev, data);
    size++;
}

//Функция вывода всей информации из списка
void List::GetAllInfo() {
    std::cout << "From List:\n";
    Node Temp = Tail;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Tail.pPrev->data.GetInfo();
        Tail.pPrev = Tail.pPrev->pPrev;
    }
    Tail = Temp;
}
//Функция вывода информации по имени
void List::GetInfo(const std::string& name) {
    Node Temp = Tail;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (Tail.pPrev->data.name == name) { Tail.pPrev->data.GetInfo(); break; }
        else Tail.pPrev = Tail.pPrev->pPrev;
    }
    Tail = Temp;
}

//Функция записи списка в файл
void List::WriteFile() {
    Node Temp = Tail;
    std::ofstream file("list.txt");
    if (!file) {
        std::cout << "Ошибка записи в List.txt\n";
    }
    else {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            file << Tail.pPrev->data;
            Tail.pPrev = Tail.pPrev->pPrev;
        }
        file.close();
    }

    Tail = Temp;
}
//main.cpp

#include "Headers.h"


int main() {

    

    BD bd;  //создание пустой базы
    bd["Ivanov"] = Data(30, male, 30000);   //если Ivanov-а в базе еще нет, то
    bd["Muraev"] = Data(18, male, 0);
    bd["Param"] = Data(27, male, 30000);
    bd["Purum"] = Data(30, male, 2);
    bd["Ivbnov"] = Data(31, female, 4);
    bd["Ivcnov"] = Data(27, female, 3);
    bd["Ivdnov"] = Data(27, female, 3);
    bd["Ivenov"] = Data(27, female, 3);
    bd["Ivfnov"] = Data(27, female, 3);
    //bd["Muraev"] = Data(18, male, 2);
    //bd["vonavI"] = Data(131, male, 4);
    //bd["vearuM"] = Data(19, female, 1);
    //bd["Param"] = Data(78, male, 0.5);
    //добавление, если уже есть, то замена его реквизитов
    bd.GetAllInfo(bd);  //вывод информации обо всех сотрудниках
    bd.GetInfo("Ivanov");
    bd.GetInfo("vonavI");
    bd.WriteFile();

    return 0;
}



Если переношу функцию check(); в конец Data& BD::operator [] (const std::string& name) Она просто не вызывается, но данные не теряются.
